# converting multiple png to mp4, all frames are the first image

Tags: video, avconv

I am trying to convert multiple images (.png) into a video mp4.
I am using avconv, I already made it work before but I can't remember how ...
I am using ubuntu 14.04, I had the avconv 9.something, I just updated it to the version 11.6 by downloading it on the libav website.

I have around 70 png that I want to convert into a mp4.
I am typing the following command:

```
avconv -r 10  -i implant%4d.png -b:v 1000k test.mp4
```

or

```
avconv -r 10 -start_number 1 -stats -i "implant%4d.png" -b:v 1000k test.mp4
```

the video in output as the good number of frame, but all of them are the first image.
the output on the terminal is the following:

```
avconv version 11.6, Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the Libav developers
  built on Apr 28 2016 08:46:48 with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1)
Input #0, image2, from 'implant%4d.png':
  Duration: 00:00:02.88, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0.0: Video: png, rgb24, 1350x982, 25 fps, 25 tbn
File 'test.mp4' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
Output #0, mp4, to 'test.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf56.1.0
    Stream #0.0: Video: mpeg4, yuv420p, 1350x982, q=2-31, 1000 kb/s, 10  fps, 10 tbn, 10 tbc
   Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.1.0 mpeg4
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (png (native) -> mpeg4 (native))
Press ctrl-c to stop encoding
frame=   72 fps= 26 q=2.0 Lsize=     362kB time=7.10 bitrate= 417.4kbits/s
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the wildcard.

From implant%4d.png to **implant%04d.png**

Works for me.

Comment: `implant%4d.png` means `implant1.png` to `implant9999.png`, while `implant%04d.png` means `implant0001.png` to `implant9999.png` (note the noughts)